# Storing jobs to do later in quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a web application made in java and uses tomcat which i am using to convert html pages to pdf.What i want is when a user chooses what html pages to convert to pdf,the job is queued and is done after sometime,usually when the server is less burdened.

> *1.Client Makes Request to Server i.e example.com/topdf*
>
> *2.The request is received and is stored and is executed when the server is ready*

I am reading the Quartz documentation and i have my doubts if this is how i should be using a job scheduler.Can i use quartz this way?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement code to process the users' requests and store them somehow.

Add a Quartz job to run e.g. every minute, When it's started check whether there are some stored requests to be evaluated. If there are some check whether server has enough resources and if yes evaluate these stored requests. Else exit the job and wait for another start one minute later.